# Restrofit deserializing JSON response

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I have an auth REST api that returns the following JSON response (I am following http://jsonapi.org convention)

```
{ "user" : { "id" : 1, "first_name" : "Jack" } }
```

I noticed that Retrofit/Gson does not parse out the root `user` object automagically? so instead of giving a `User` object in my success callback, I am doing the following, was wondering if theres a better way to do this? I am new to Retrofit/Android.

```
authService.signIn(authJson, new Callback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void success(JsonObject jsonObject, Response response) {
        User user = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.get("user"), User.class);
        progress.hide();
        signInSuccess(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Retrofit automatically serializes if your API returns `{ "id" : 1, "first_name" : "Jack" }` (in which case you can use `Callback<User>`) instead of `{STRING -> User}` what you're now returning. You might want to checkout the chapter [JSON CONVERSION](http://square.github.io/retrofit) to see if you can do something about the default behavior though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should just create a wrapping class like that:

```
class UserWrapper {
      User user;
}
```

and make that the return type of the Retrofit interface.

There's an issue with your solution as well. If I remember correctly, Retrofit streams the network data directly to Gson on the fly. Your solution, on the other hand, will parse `User` object *after* the full response is received, and on the main thread as well.

The penalty may not be that significant for a single request, but it's something you'd probably want to avoid for general optimization.

Comment: Can you please point me to some documentation or code that shows Retrofit parsing the network data on the fly?

Comment: You can take a look at [GsonConverter.java](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/converter/GsonConverter.java) in fromBody method and in [RestAdapter.java](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java) as well. The InputStream from the response is not read by Retrofit, but is sent to the converter (by default GSON) directly through [streaming](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming).

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own deserializer, register it in `GsonBuilder` and pass it to the `RestAdapter`

Registering Type:

```
            GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
            gb.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
            gb.registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserDeserializerDeserializer());
            OkClient okClient = new OkClient();     
            Builder restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder();
            restAdapter.setEndpoint(BASE_URL);
            restAdapter.setExecutors(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), new MainThreadExecutor());
            restAdapter.setConverter(new GsonConverter(gb.create()));
            mRestAdapter = restAdapter.build();//
```

UserDeserializer class:

```
public class UserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<User>{
    private static Gson sGson = new Gson();
    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonElement arg0, Type arg1,
            JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
       JsonObject userObject = arg0.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("user");
       return sGson.fromJson(userObject, arg1);

}
```

You are deserializing the response in the `success` method, which could hang the UI (under assumption you are using `MainThreadExecutor` for callbacks) in the cases where you have huge huge response.

Approach with writing your own deserializer will parse the response on the background thread too.